# Como Criar div que surge na rolagem da página

Tags: javascript, html, div

Alguns sites possuem uma `div` que surge na lateral da página conforme chega próximo do final da mesma.

Não sei como se chama mas tenho um exemplo:
 nas páginas dos posts do site http://www.ovelhasvoadoras.com.br/ surge esta `div`.

Qual o nome desse tipo de janela/div? Alguém sabe como fazer ou conhece algum tutorial bacana?

Comment: Se alguma das respostas for satisfatória, considere marcar uma resposta como resposta para sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

### Rolagem infinita

[image]
<sub>Fonte: Reprodução/[SmashingMagazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/infinite-scrolling-lets-get-to-the-bottom-of-this/)</sub>

São *scripts* criados para melhorar a experiência do usuário na rolagem da página. Também pode ser chamado pelo seus termos em inglês:

- *lazy loading*
- *endless scrolling*
- *autopager*
- *endless pages*

Um bom exemplo é o seu *feed* de notícias do Facebook, que toda vez que você chega ao fim da página, ele recarrega-a com novos *posts*, sem precisar atualizar a página, ou coisa do tipo.

---

**Steady.js**

Uma biblioteca Javascript para criação do efeito em qualquer página HTML.

- [Repositório no GitHub](https://github.com/WPOTools/steady.js)
- [Documentação e guias](https://wpotools.github.io/steady.js/)

**jScroll**
Um plugin jQuery de rolagem infinita, ele pode carregar o conteúdo via AJAX, por isso dou ênfase à ele.

- [Página oficial](http://jscroll.com/) (contém o download, exemplos e tutorial de uso)

**ScrollMe**

Um plugin jQuery que te auxilia na criação de efeitos para rolagem também em qualquer página HTML. Tem muitos efeitos e as opções para customização são bem vastas.

> **Nota:** esse não é um plugin para rolagem infinita, mas os dois em conjunto dão um efeito muito bacana. O ScrollMe é para efeitos de rolagem.

- [Repositório no GitHub](https://github.com/nckprsn/scrollme)
- [Página oficial](http://scrollme.nckprsn.com/)